# When to use addEventHandler method

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me when to use the addEventListener() method? For a while now I have kept seeing this method in documentation  and am confused because I know that there is already onclick event handlers to use so my guess was the addEventListener()  event handler proper use is when a variable has already used a event property or method in the script, hence “add” event listener. Can someone tell me is this the proper usage of this method and when it is supposed to be used?

Comment: I think either your terminology or your language tag is incorrect

Comment: Ah youre right. I meant to add event listener method I have edited my post